# InaccessibleObjectException while working in gson 2.10.1 with Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gson, java-17

Currently, I am using **Java 11 with Spring Boot 2.7.9 and gson version 2.9.0**

Now trying to upgrade to **Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1.2 and gson 2.10.1**

While the project is checking with pre-integration-test in spring-boot-maven-plugin(3.1.2), getting the following exception. Using dockerfile-maven-plugin version 1.4.13 in pom.xml.

Not sure, what am I missing with the version or due to any version conflict. Need your help here.

Advance thanks.

```
    Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: An exception occurred processing Appender rollingFile
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.DefaultErrorHandler.error(DefaultErrorHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.handleAppenderError(AppenderControl.java:165)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:158)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:590)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:573)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.logParent(LoggerConfig.java:621)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:592)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:573)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:507)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:148)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2038)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:1992)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:1975)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1834)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1692)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:261)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:221)
        at org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupInfo(SpringApplication.java:618)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.myproject.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:12)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.lang.StackTraceElement#classLoaderName' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:842)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:812)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:759)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:736)
        at com.myproject.logger.MyLog4jLayout.toSerializable(MyLog4jLayout.java:55)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:283)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:193)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:34)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:179)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:172)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:163)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:304)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.lang.StackTraceElement.classLoaderName accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3b07a0d6
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)
        ... 50 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:44 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-27T16:28:38+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.2:start (pre-integration-test) on project myproject: Failed to connect to MBean server at port 9001: Could not invoke shutdown operation: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
[ERROR]         java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Adding pom.xml as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>myproject</name>
  
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>xxxx</id>
      <name>xxxx</name>
     <url>xxxx</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>The Repo</name>
      <url>xxxx</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>xxxx</id>
      <url>xxxx</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-security.version>6.1.2</spring-security.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>xxxx</docker.image.prefix>
    <jdbc.version>19.3.0.0</jdbc.version>
    <server.port>9095</server.port>
    <flyway.version>9.17.0</flyway.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.20.0</log4j2.version>
    <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.16.0</commons-codec.version>
    <gson.version>2.10.1</gson.version>
    <skip.it>false</skip.it>
    <skip.mdp>true</skip.mdp>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
              <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
             <artifactId>accessors-smart</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>32.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.29.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
       <version>${flyway.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.28</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-coverage-report</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <dataFile>${project.basedir}/jacoco-report/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <jvmArguments>-Xdebug
            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006
          </jvmArguments>
          <maxAttempts>360</maxAttempts>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:${server.port}/public-openapi.yaml</apiDocsUrl>
          <outputFileName>public-openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
          <outputDir>${project.basedir}</outputDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>bash</executable>
          <workingDirectory>xxxx</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>build.sh</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${skip.mdp}</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
          only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>
                      org.codehaus.mojo
                    </groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                      exec-maven-plugin
                    </artifactId>
                    <versionRange>
                      [1.6.0,)
                    </versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why using gson instead fast jackson?

Comment: gson was already part of the project and if we change it now we need to change the code as well. Hence wanted to go ahead with gson.

Comment: It was already the wrong way in SB 2.X so it is as well in SB 3.X ... I would migrate the project ... it's easier... And So how many code could it be? Using a good ide etc. shouldn't be that a big issue... ? Furthermore why using dockerfile-maven-plugin instead the jib parts of SB 3.X https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#container-images Apart from that it looks like that gson seemed to be not JDK 17 ready... also a full pom file would be helpful here... ?

Comment: Added the pom file.

Comment: Also updated with the full exception stack trace. It is coming while executing: mvn clean install

Comment: One important part of it: when I make 'skip.it' as true, then I do not face the issue as it skips that step.

Comment: Why using different version of jackson instead of using the one which is given via SB? ... And furthermore mixing different jackson versions ... Why defining jakarta verisons separate instead of using the one which coming via SB (which is the same version!!) also jakarta-servlet-api same thing.. (SB!!)... ? Also use the one spring-web wich is given via SB ... Using an older version of hibernate-validator instead of the one which is given by SB... defining commons-lang3 same versions as already given by SB... so no version needed...jboss-logging older version defined than getting via SB ...

Comment: Mockito verison defined much older than the version given via SB(5.3.1)...why using byte-buddy? Why using maven-dependency-plugin ?? What should be unpacked??? layers for docker image? Use the one which is comming via SB3... check the docs...Why defining spring-web using the same version as SB already defines? So remove the version if you really use that directly...

Comment: The dockerfile-maven-plugin is abandoned... Use the one which is provided by SB...

Comment: As suggested by you, changed the same, but still getting the same exception.

Comment: Updated the pom.xml in the original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method `com.myproject.logger.MyLog4jLayout.toSerializable` indirectly tries to use Gson to serialize a `Throwable` to JSON. Gson does not have a built-in adapter for `Throwable` so it falls back to using reflection, accessing internal fields which represent implementation details.
In JDK 17 access to internal JDK implementation details was further restricted ([JEP 403](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403)), which is why you are experiencing this exception.

If you still want to serialize `Throwable` instances with Gson, you will have to write a custom `TypeAdapter` which performs the serialization. See [this comment](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2352#issuecomment-1481864208) on a related GitHub issue for more information and also sample code for such a `TypeAdapter`.

Also in general be careful that you don't accidentally use Gson's reflection-based adapter for implementation details of other third-party libraries, because they could change at any point and also might not necessarily produce useful JSON data. You can use Gson's [`ReflectionAccessFilter` feature](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#addReflectionAccessFilter(com.google.gson.ReflectionAccessFilter)) to restrict on which classes Gson may use reflection to perform serialization.

Comment: As an workaround solution, I've added "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" in the configuration argLine. With this Compile and Build are pass. While I am deploying this to server, getting same error. Need your help please.

Comment: Do you mean even with the solution shown in my answer you are getting this exception? In that case check if this is also for `Throwable` or for a different JDK class for which you might also have to write a custom `TypeAdapter`. The `--add-opens` workaround only hides the actual problem, which is that you are are (accidentally) serializing JDK internals; and you would need to provide `--add-opens` both during test execution and for your normal deployment.

Comment: It works with the custom TypeAdapter. Thanks.